# Filter pandas groupby by comparing to consecutive groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
       date1      date2
0 2015-01-01 2014-12-11
1 2015-01-01 2014-12-30
2 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
3 2015-01-02 2015-12-30
4 2015-01-02 2015-01-01
5 2015-01-02 2015-01-02
6 2015-01-03 2015-01-01
7 2015-01-03 2015-01-02
8 2015-01-03 2015-01-03
```

I want to group this dataframe on `date1` and then filter each group down by records where `date2` >= the PREVIOUS group's `date1` (and none of the records with the smallest `date1` would be filtered out). My final goal is to count the number of items left in each group after the filter has been applied.

The filtering would leave the following rows:

```
       date1    date2
0 2015-01-01  2014-12-11
1 2015-01-01  2014-12-30
2 2015-01-02  2015-01-01
4 2015-01-02  2015-01-01
5 2015-01-02  2015-01-02
7 2015-01-03  2015-01-02
8 2015-01-03  2015-01-03
```

And then the count would be:

```
    date1    count
0 2015-01-01 3
1 2015-01-02 2
2 2015-01-03 2
```

I can get the groups as follows:

```
groups = df.sort('timestamp', ascending=False).groupby('timestamp')
```

but I can't think of a way to do the filtering and counting such that consecutive groups are compared.

Comment: Your middle data frame after the words 'the following rows' should have `date1` in row 2 as `2015-1-1`

Answer (score 2):

***one line using [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)***

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df, df[['date1']].assign(d_=df.date1),
    allow_exact_matches=False
).fillna(0).query('date2 >= d_').groupby('date1').size()

date1
2015-01-01    3
2015-01-02    2
2015-01-03    2
dtype: int64
```

---

***explanation***

[from the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

> For each row in the left DataFrame, we select the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s key. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

So I make `df` merge with itself on `date1` with parameter `allow_exact_matches` as `False`.  This gets me easy access to "previous group".

From there, it's a `query` to filter, `groupby` + `size` to get counts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create `Series` `s` for map previous value by `groups`, also first `NaN` values was replaced by [min](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) (faster as `fillna` is use `at`):

```
#if df is not sorted by column date1
df = df.sort_values('date1')

s = pd.Series(df.date1.values, index = df.date1).drop_duplicates().shift()
s.at[s.index[0]] = pd.Timestamp.min
print (s)
date1
2015-01-01   1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225
2015-01-02   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000
2015-01-03   2015-01-02 00:00:00.000000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and filter values, for count [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) boolean mask:

```
print (df.groupby('date1')['date2']
         .apply(lambda x: x[s[x.name] <= x])
         .reset_index(name='Count'))

       date1  level_1      Count
0 2015-01-01        0 2014-12-11
1 2015-01-01        1 2014-12-30
2 2015-01-01        2 2015-01-01
3 2015-01-02        3 2015-12-30
4 2015-01-02        4 2015-01-01
5 2015-01-02        5 2015-01-02
6 2015-01-03        7 2015-01-02
7 2015-01-03        8 2015-01-03

df = df.groupby('date1')['date2']
       .apply(lambda x: (s[x.name] <= x).sum())
       .reset_index(name='Count')

print (df)
       date1  Count
0 2015-01-01      3
1 2015-01-02      3
2 2015-01-03      2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a column called `previous_group` so that you can visually see the previous group for each `date1` grouping.

```
df['previous_group'] = df['date1'].drop_duplicates().shift(1)
df['previous_group'] = df['previous_group'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

#### Output

Note: I changed date2 for row 3 to the year 2014 which is what I think you intended.

```
       date1      date2 previous_group
0 2015-01-01 2014-12-11            NaT
1 2015-01-01 2014-12-30            NaT
2 2015-01-01 2015-01-01            NaT
3 2015-01-02 2014-12-30     2015-01-01
4 2015-01-02 2015-01-01     2015-01-01
5 2015-01-02 2015-01-02     2015-01-01
6 2015-01-03 2015-01-01     2015-01-02
7 2015-01-03 2015-01-02     2015-01-02
8 2015-01-03 2015-01-03     2015-01-02
```

#### Filter out rows

Then you can filter out the unwanted rows with boolean indexing, keeping only those that meet the condition and the first group which has a missing value for each time.

```
df1 = df[(df['date2'] >= df['previous_group']) | df['previous_group'].isnull()]
```

#### Output

```
       date1      date2 previous_group
0 2015-01-01 2014-12-11            NaT
1 2015-01-01 2014-12-30            NaT
2 2015-01-01 2015-01-01            NaT
4 2015-01-02 2015-01-01     2015-01-01
5 2015-01-02 2015-01-02     2015-01-01
7 2015-01-03 2015-01-02     2015-01-02
8 2015-01-03 2015-01-03     2015-01-02
```

#### Count dates

Then you can use `value_counts` to count up the dates

```
df1['date1'].value_counts()
```

#### Output

```
2015-01-01    3
2015-01-03    2
2015-01-02    2
```

So altogether it would be:

```
df['previous_group'] = df['date1'].drop_duplicates().shift(1)
df['previous_group'] = df['previous_group'].fillna(method='ffill')
df1 = df[(df['date2'] >= df['previous_group']) | df['previous_group'].isnull()]
df1['date1'].value_counts()
```